# Compute exponential of sum of Kronecker products of non-commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, matrix-exponential, kronecker-product

In the context of [CTMCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain) I want to compute following [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential):

$$\exp(M_1\otimes M_2 + M_3\otimes M_4 + D_1\otimes D_2 + D_3\otimes D_4)$$

with:

- $\otimes$ being the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product),
- all matrices being square,
- all matrices having the same size,
- all $M_i$ having all entries on a off-diagonal or diagonal,
- all $D_i$ being diagonal.

Furthermore for each $i$, the $D_i$ have the entries of the $M_i$ shifted column-wise onto the main diagonal.

Example:

$$M_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\\ 0&0&0\\ \end{pmatrix},
M_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ \end{pmatrix},
M_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ \end{pmatrix},
M_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\\ 0&0&0\\ \end{pmatrix}\\
D_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\\ \end{pmatrix},
D_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&0\\ \end{pmatrix},
D_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ \end{pmatrix},
D_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

The Kronecker product can give very large results and since the matrices are sparse it is not feasible to explicitly store the result. Instead I would like to use this property of the Kronecker product:

$$\exp(A\otimes B) = \exp(A) \otimes \exp(B)$$

However, there is the sum $+$ in the way and since it seems like my matrices generally do not commute, I can not use

$$\exp(A + B) = \exp(A)\exp(B)$$

Are there any properties of $+$, $\otimes$ and $\exp()$ that I can use to compute all $\otimes$ after $\exp()$?

Comment: The "property of the Kronecker product" you refer to is incorrect. For example, we can see that it is not true for $A = B = 1$ (or $A = B = I$ if you prefer).

Comment: For this computation, I think the only reasonable approach is to calculate $M_1\otimes M_2 + M_3\otimes M_4 + D_1\otimes D_2 + D_3\otimes D_4$ and then compute the exponential of this $9\times 9$ matrix in the usual way

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for your response. You are right... I've seen $\exp(A \oplus B) = \exp(A) \otimes \exp(B)$ and mistook the $\oplus$ to be $\otimes$.